# REG x8 Memory vs Normal?

Tags: memory, upgrade

I'm looking to upgrade my Dell PowerEdge T310 server and have come down to two memory options.

Both are 1x4GB @ 1333MHz, Dual Rank but one of them is $4 more and has "REG x8" added to the title. What's the difference? Which one is faster/better preformance?

Specifically these two products:

http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/partsinfo.asp?root=us&LinkBack=http://www.kingston.com&ktcpartno=KTD-PE313E/4G

http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/partsinfo.asp?root=us&LinkBack=http://www.kingston.com&ktcpartno=KTD-PE3138/4G

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The REG X8 memory is [registered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_memory) ECC memory, the other is not.

The X8 is in reference to the density; [Paul writes a great piece](http://www.motherboardpoint.com/ddr-high-and-low-density-t107385.html) which explains in depth the density and thus the X8 and X16 references.

> At the 512Megabit level, some chip
>   types might be 16Mx16, 32Mx8, 64Mx4.
>   The "x16" and "x8" types are defined
>   as  acceptable by JEDEC, for making
>   unbuffered modules. With the  "x16"
>   chips, four of those chips on one side
>   of the module,  makes a bank.
>
> With the "x8" type, it takes eight of
>   those chips on the side of a module,
>   to make a bank. Basically, it takes as
>   many chips as is necessary to make a
>   64 bit grouping (as the bus interface
>   on a DIMM is 64 bits wide).

X8 would be a low density chip, so make sure your motherboard supports it. The X8 is in reference to the memory configuration on the chip itself.

In terms of better; that is subjective. One is geared towards scaling and addresses technical limitations of scaling by way of ECC.

You should see if your server currently has ECC or non-ECC memory in it. If it has low density ECC memory, go with that, otherwise go with the non-ECC memory.

Comment: I understand the "registered" part- is it better than non-registered? what about the "x8"?

Comment: @sman591 Better is subjective; ECC is slower than non-ECC memory; answer updated.

Comment: @sman591  On the other hand, ECC provides better data integrity than standard memory.